# I'm trying to get json objects to render in a list using REACT

Tags: reactjs

I'm fetching an API using REACT and trying to get the results to render in a list. I see the output in the console but it's not rendering on the page. I just want to of the objects to render. My REACT syntax is fairly new.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: 10
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var component = this;
    var url;

    fetch("https://api.spacexdata.com/v2/launches")
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(json) {
        var data = json;
        console.log(data[0]);
        console.log("hi" + data[0].flight_number);
        component.setState({
          data: json
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>elo{launchInfo}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
    var launchInfo = this.state[0].data.flight_number || "";
  }
}

const docs = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, docs);
```

Comment: Have you tried moving launchInfo before anything is returned in the render?

Comment: @fungusanthrax I did and data came back undefined. I'm not getting any errors jn the current state. Just not rendering on the page.

Comment: Whoever down voted this needs to comment why they did. I see no valid reason to down vote, therefore I am up voting to negate it.

Answer (score 1):

Intention seems to be to look for first item in data, not state. Like this:

```
var launchInfo = this.state.data[0].flight_number || "";
```

Comment: What this guy said. You had the `[0]` in the wrong spot

Comment: I also threw **[this demo together to demonstrate](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n5hjo1)**

Comment: @Ted Thanks for the demo. I was trying to use map but kept getting errors. Your code showed me what I was doing wrong. Thank you sooo much!

Comment: @thinkbliss sure thing, glad to help